# Using same view for controller actions with similar models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have lots of models with the same format(like the following models and just with Id and Name properties), all of them are inherited from the **Entity model** .

```
  public abstract class Entity 
        {
          public int Id { get; set; }
        }
     public class Exapmle1 : Entity
        {
             public string Name { get; set; }
        }
     public class Exapmle2 : Entity
        {
             public string Name { get; set; }
        }
     public class Exapmle3 : Entity
        {
             public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

I prefer not to implement ***several controllers and correspondence views*** for each model in CRUD actions.
Is there any way to get minimum implementation??
For example, having just **one** Index View(listing) for all the implemented Controllers that using the same format models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the combination of Generic Controller and **shared** view as the best way. In this case also there could be an authentication for each controller separately.

**Generic Controller :**

```
 public abstract class GenericController<T> : Controller
        where T : BaseInformation
    {  //Controller Implementation for Index, Create, Edit, Delete   }
```

**View** in Shared folder

```
@model BaseInformation
//Model Implementation
```

**Final controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
      public class Base1Controller : GenericController<Base1>
        {
        }
[Authorize(Roles = "Helpdesk")]
        public class Base2Controller : GenericController<Base2>
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a view with dynamic view model and controller action that accepts Entity (your base class). It could look like this

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(Entity foo)
{
    if(foo is Example1)
{
    var e1 = foo as Example1;
    //do your stuff
}

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model dynamic

   @{
    ViewBag.Title = "IndexNotStonglyTyped";
    }

<h2>Index Not Stongly Typed</h2>

<p>
    <label>@Model.Name</label>
    <label>@Model.Id</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method that can work well when you have closely related groups of entities (or any other object for that matter) is to split them into composable interfaces, for example:

```
public interface IIdIdentity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface INameIdentity
{
    int Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IYourGroup : IIdIdentity, INameIdentity
{

}

public class Exapmle1 : IYourGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view can accept any entity of type `IYourGroup` providing your domain entity fulfills the interface.